# Batch jobs sitting in "Holding" status after flex queue turned on

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

Since turning on the flex queue, I am seeing batch jobs that previously executed near-instantly now sitting in the "Holding" status for a very long time. It appears that only one job per hour (on the half hour) is executed; jobs submitted outside of that time frame sit in "Holding" for up to an hour!

I can click the "Run" link on the Holding job in the Apex Jobs view and the job gets submitted and processed fairly quickly.

Possibly relevant: these jobs are submitted from a scheduled job. There are a maximum of 2 jobs submitted at any time; usually there is just one submitted job but it sits in "Holding" for a long time.

Is there an easy way to fix this behavior to get jobs running smoothly and frequently again? Will switching to the Queueable interface improve the situation?

Comment: We have a similar setup in production, and ours never hangs. Maybe you need to have salesforce take a look for phantom jobs that might be causing issues.